# Trying to install Brew on MacOS 10.10.5. Getting "invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)"

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install Homebrew on MacOS 10.10.5, after running the line:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I go through all the installation process, but get this error in the end:

```
-e:234:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
from -e:234:in `<main>'
```

And I can't even run `brew doctor` or `brew update` afterwards, since I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:48:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:48:in `<top (required)>'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/Library/brew.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by adding the following to my .bashrc file in my home directory:

```
#   Set Paths
#   ------------------------------------------------------------
    export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/"
    export PATH="/usr/local/git/bin:/sw/bin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

I found this code in [this article on customizing your bash profile](https://natelandau.com/my-mac-osx-bash_profile/). In the article, the author adds this line to the .bash_profile file, but it seemed to work better for me inside the .bashrc file.

On a Mac, you can reveal these files in Finder, for editing, by going into your home directory in Finder, and then pressing three keys `Command + Shift + .`.